# Why is there a memory leak in my program?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, linked-list, c++17

I have implemented a singly-linked-list where there is a `SinglyList` class, and `struct node`, `node *head` as private members of the class; and wrote a destructor to delete it. I used CRT library to check for memory leaks using `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` method. When I debug the code, it shows in the debug console that memory leaks are found, which is strange since I wrote a destructor to delete it.

This is shown in the debug console:-
[image]

Here is the node class:-

```
struct node 
{
    int data = NULL;
    node*next = NULL;
};
```

Here is the destructor:-

```
SinglyList::~SinglyList()
{
    node*curr = head,*next;
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        next = curr->next;
        delete curr;
        curr = next;
    }
}
```

I don't understand, how can there be memory leaks when all nodes are deleted, kindly help.

Edit:

SinglyList.hpp:-

```
#pragma once 
#include<iostream>

class SinglyList
{
private:
    struct node 
    {
        int data = NULL;
        node*next = NULL;
    };
    node*head;
public:
    SinglyList();
    void Append(const int&);
    void Prepend(const int&);
    void Print();
    void Insert(const int&,const int&);
    void Delete(const int&);
    void Reverse();
    bool isEmpty();
    ~SinglyList();
};

SinglyList::SinglyList()
{
    head = NULL;
}

SinglyList::~SinglyList()
{
    node*curr = head,*next;
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        next = curr->next;
        delete curr;
        curr = next;
    }
}

void SinglyList::Append(const int&data)
{
    node*n = new node{data};
    if(!head)
    {
        head = n;
        return;
    }
    node*ptr = head;
    while(ptr->next)
        ptr = ptr->next;
    ptr->next = n;
}

void SinglyList::Prepend(const int&data)
{
    node*n = new node{data};
    if(!head)
    {
        head = n;
        return;
    }
    n->next = head;
    head = n;
}

void SinglyList::Print()
{
    if(!head)
        return;
    node*ptr = head;
    while(ptr)
    {
        std::cout<<ptr->data<<' ';
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

void SinglyList::Insert(const int&pos,const int&data)
{
    if(pos == 1)
    {
        Prepend(data);
        return;
    }
    node*n = new node{data};
    node*ptr = head;
    for(int i = 1;i!=pos-1;i++)
        ptr = ptr->next;
    n->next = ptr->next;
    ptr->next = n;
}

void SinglyList::Delete(const int&pos)
{
    if(!head)
        return;
    node*ptr = head;
    if(pos == 1)
    {
        head= head->next;
        delete ptr;
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 1;i!= pos-1;i++)
        ptr = ptr->next;
    node*temp = ptr->next;
    ptr->next = temp->next;
    delete temp;
}

void SinglyList::Reverse()
{
    if(!head)
        return;
    node*curr = head,*prev = NULL,*next = NULL;
    while(curr)
    {
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    head = prev;
}

bool SinglyList::isEmpty()
{
    return (!head);
}
```

main.cpp:-

```
#include"SinglyList.hpp"
#include<crtdbg.h>

int main()
{
    SinglyList nums{};
    nums.Append(10);
    nums.Append(20);
    nums.Append(30);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the destructor actually get called?

Comment: Do you have exactly 3 nodes in your list?

Comment: @Divij Manchanda Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `node * curr = head, *next;`  I recommend splitting this into two statements.

Comment: Noting that leaked item 177 appears to be a node that points to leaked item 178, which appears to be a node that points to leaked item 179, which is a node that points to `NULL`. @500-InternalServerError's question is worth paying attention to.

Comment: Please show a [mre] as Vlad asked for. If you don't answer your own question while preparing it - it will help us to help you find the problem a whole lot faster.

Comment: `while (head) delete exchange(head, head->next);`

Comment: you posted some code.  Not enough to show the problem.

Comment: The dump suggests that you created a list with three nodes with values 10, 20 and 30 respectively, and didn't `delete` the list. But your problem is not supported by the code. You should provide the code that lead to this dump, which necessarily should include the creation of the list with these three nodes.

Comment: I have edited the draft by adding more code to demonstrate my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You print the leaks before the list gets deleted. Try this instead:

```
#include"SinglyList.hpp"
#include<crtdbg.h>

int main()
{
    {
        SinglyList nums{};
        nums.Append(10);
        nums.Append(20);
        nums.Append(30);
    }

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Then, you'll show the actual leaks after your list gets destroyed.

Comment: Yeah, this really works; but I don't understand that, I used the _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() method before the return statement, then how does adding the curly brackets help ?

Comment: Without the extra scope, your memory gets freed *after* main() returns. So, even if you put the leak check as the very last statement, at this point the list destructor didn't run yet. It would only run after main() returned. With the extra curly brackets, the list destructor gets to run before  _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks.

Comment: @DivijManchanda Another way to approach this would be to implement a `Clear()` method that `~SinglyList()` calls, and then you can also call `Clear()` yourself before calling `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`. Same effect.